# Dot Product in C with OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I have written a code on dot product using `OpenMP` but when I execute it's going to deadlock. Here is the code:

```
double test02 ( int n, double x[], double y[] )
{
   double xdoty = 0.0;
   int nthrds; 
   int tid, nthreads, i ;
   double dot_seg[2];
   omp_set_num_threads(2);

   #pragma omp parallel default (none) \
    shared (n, nthrds, x, y,  dot_seg) private( i, nthreads, tid)
    {
         nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
         tid = omp_get_thread_num();
         if (tid == 0) nthreads = nthrds;


         for(i=tid, dot_seg[tid] =0.0; i< n ; i+= nthreads)
         {
              dot_seg[tid] = dot_seg[tid] + x[i]*y[i];

         }
     }

   for (int j=0 ; j< nthrds; j=j+1)      
           xdoty = xdoty + dot_seg[j];

   return xdoty;

}
```

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you've mixed up `nthrds` and `nthreads`.

Comment: `nthreads` is only set in the if, when `tid==0`?

Comment: You are right, it worked when i interchanged nthreads and nthrds, Thanks